# How to disable clicking in Seagate ST3000DM001?

Tags: configuration, hard-disk

Recently I bought this disk and I cannot get rid of funny clicking -- funny because normally not configured disk make dry click.

This one make click like a sweet chirp. But besides this, this click occurs every several seconds, and it is annoying.

I tried as usual: `hdparm -B 254` but it changed nothing.

So does anyone know how to disable that clicking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and the fix is here:

http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Barracuda-XT-Barracuda-Barracuda/ANNOUNCEMENT-New-firmware-update-for-Barracuda-1TB-platter/td-p/162362

Comment: Thank you. For other readers -- basically it is (finally) newer firmware. However setup is only for Mac or Windows, not Linux.

Answer (score 1):

A hard drive should not produce any clicking sounds. Especially because you describe the sounds as *funny* I assume that the sounds are unusual and therefore the drive is not operating correctly. Your data might be in danger.

I would immediately back up the data and send it back for warranty (you can wipe it before if your  data is confidential).

Comment: No, this is pretty normal, unfortunately. Every disk I bought recently required this tweak with disabling parking heads. The only difference is, the pitch now is different, and I cannot disable it (the second is most important). But since this is my first 3TB disk, with 3 platters, I assume that such side effect as pitch could differ after all.